# Missing argument and undefined variable 'text'

Tags: error, undefined-variable

Unsure on how to debug this issue. Recently started getting hundreds of these in `system.log`.

- 2013-08-30T11:20:46+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 1 for Mage_Core_Block_Text::setText()  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text.php on line 36
- 2013-08-30T11:20:46+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: text  in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text.php on line 38

This is filling the log up at a rapid pace as they are being thrown on every page load.

Coming from the Magento core yet there have been no modifications to the core at all.

Don't suppose anyone has any ideas on this at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably there is a block with type `core/text` and the method `setText` is called on your block without a parameter. 
This can come from a layout file, from a declaration like this:

```
<block type="core/text" ...>
    <action method="setText"></action><!-- missing parameter here --> 
</block>
```

Or from a controller or other block. something like

```
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/text');
$block->setText();
```

use xDebug and put a break point in the line suggested in the error message and see the stacktrace.
Or you can look in all your files for the text `setText` and see if you can find something fishy.

Comment: Ahaa, yes, makes sense. Thanks @Marius. Unfortunately I haven't managed to get xDebug working on our servers yet but I'll bet this is being caused from a layout file somewhere. Will investigate this first - thanks.

Comment: Found it. `page.xml` missing `<text>` / `</text>` declaration in a `setText` action. Nice one @Marius and thanks!